# How to convert list of HTML table tags into Google sheet Table using formula?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In one cell, I run have `=IMPORTDATA("https://www.domain.mu/en/handler/GetIndicativeForex")`

This results in a list of HTML table codes below.

[image]

```
<table class="table table--decorated">
<tr>
<th><span class="visually-hidden">Currency</span></th>
<th class="content-right">Buy</th>
<th class="content-right">Sell</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>AUD</td>
<td class="content-right">31.32</td>
<td class="content-right">32.57</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>EUR</td>
<td class="content-right">45.75</td>
<td class="content-right">47.12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>GBP</td>
<td class="content-right">54.48</td>
<td class="content-right">56.11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>JPY</td>
<td class="content-right">33.39</td>
<td class="content-right">34.73</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>USD</td>
<td class="content-right">44.90</td>
<td class="content-right">45.80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ZAR</td>
<td class="content-right">2.68</td>
<td class="content-right">2.85</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How to convert this into a clean table like the image below using only formula?

I did it with the App script before but I wanted to stop using script, just excel formula.

[image]

Comment: Please see the URL below on how to import HTML tables into google sheets. 

https://www.automateexcel.com/how-to/import-html-table/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but this is not using formula.

Comment: just a suggestion, is  it possible to create and save it as an HTML file, upload it to a remote webserver and reference it via its URL using the IMPORTHTML formula

=IMPORTHTML("http://www.yourdomain.com/tablename.html", "table",0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a suggestion, is it possible to create and save it as an HTML file, upload it to a remote webserver and reference it via its URL using the IMPORTHTML formula =IMPORTHTML("yourdomain.com/tablename.html", "table",0)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) directly, instead of `IMPORTDATA`. No need to upload a different HTML file:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.domain.mu/en/handler/GetIndicativeForex","table")
```

[image]